# Why the same HTML code gives different result when displayed

Tags: html, css

I'm puzzled by a phenomenon where same HTML code gives different result and hope someone could point out the catch.
I have the following HTML code to display 2 sections:

```
<section class="screen-block">
    <div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
        <a class="anchor" id="restriction"></a>
        <h4 style="display:inline;padding-right:8px">Restriction</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="=row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
       <div class="card border-success">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="screen-block">
    <div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
        <a class="anchor" id="limits"></a>
        <h4 style="display:inline;padding-right:8px">Limits</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card border-success ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The displays of two section look different: one is 10 pixels to right of the other:

[image]

Comment: is maybe this line `class="=row"`, there seems to be an extra character `=`

Comment: Thank you all for catching my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "=" in your first row div.

Your code needs to be

```html
<!-- Ignore this, is the CDN for bootstrap -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<section class="screen-block">
    <div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
        <a class="anchor" id="restriction"></a>
        <h4 style="display:inline;padding-right:8px">Restriction</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
       <div class="card border-success">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="screen-block">
    <div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
        <a class="anchor" id="limits"></a>
        <h4 style="display:inline;padding-right:8px">Limits</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card border-success ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: yeah, `<div class="=row">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<section class="screen-block">
    <div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
        <a class="anchor" id="restriction"></a>
        <h4 style="display:inline;padding-right:8px">Restriction</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> // here was your mistake
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
       <div class="card border-success">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```